# Game of Life RLE format - line ending with number

Tags: conways-game-of-life

I want to build a figure using it's RLE representation. I ran into a problem with ["Lobster"](http://conwaylife.com/patterns/83p7h1v1.rle) figure, particulary with this part:

```
10bo2bo2$
```

How should I interpret '2' in the end of line? I have no clue because there are no symbols following it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'$'` character is considered a symbol, like any other, in the RLE format, and it means "increment the row". So if there's a number before it, that means increment the row by that amount.

So if I wrote a pattern like `o5bo3$o5bo!`, it would translate into a pattern that looks like this:

```
@-----@
-------
-------
@-----@
```